How to change the style of text in PHP code?
I want to display the categories on my woocommerce page - all product loops.
I found a code to do this:
add_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', function ( ){
    global $product;
        echo wc_get_product_category_list($product->get_id());
}, 1 ); 

However the text does not look to good when more than one category (see image). So I wonder how I can add style to this? Maybe change the size of the font to 13px would make them fit one row. And also a bit of space between the category name and the product name would be nice.
How it looks now
Thank you!
I have added this code:
add_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', function ( ){
    global $product;
        echo wc_get_product_category_list($product->get_id());
}, 1 ); 

I tried some codes for font etc in the code but did not work.
I add the source code that comes up when added below suggestion:


<div class="woocommerce columns-5 "><ul class="products elementor-grid columns-5">
<li class="product type-product post-10337 status-publish first instock product_cat-instrument-pv purchasable product-type-simple">
    
<div data-item_id="10337" data-action="alg-wc-wl-toggle" class="alg-wc-wl-btn add alg-wc-wl-thumb-btn alg-wc-wl-thumb-btn-abs alg-wc-wl-thumb-btn-loop" style="inset: 17px auto auto 17px; display: block;">
    <div class="alg-wc-wl-view-state alg-wc-wl-view-state-add">
        <i class="far fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="alg-wc-wl-view-state alg-wc-wl-view-state-remove">
        <i class="fas fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
            <i class="loading fas fa-sync-alt fa-spin fa-fw"></i>
    </div><a href="https://motoroldies.rocketdigital.se/produkt/testprodukt-for-bilder-2/" class="woocommerce-LoopProduct-link woocommerce-loop-product__link"><img loading="lazy" decoding="async" src="https://motoroldies.rocketdigital.se/wp-content/uploads/2024/03/motoroldies-logga-500x368-1.png" width="150" height="113" class="woocommerce-placeholder wp-post-image" alt="Platshållare"></a><a href="https://motoroldies.rocketdigital.se/produkt-kategori/pv/elsystem/instrument-pv/" rel="tag">Instrument PV</a><h2 class="woocommerce-loop-product__title">Testprodukt för bilder</h2>
    <span class="price"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi>500,00&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">kr</span></bdi></span></span>
<div class="woocommerce-loop-product__buttons"><a href="?add-to-cart=10337" data-quantity="1" class="button product_type_simple add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart" data-product_id="10337" data-product_sku="3" aria-label="Lägg till i varukorgen: ”Testprodukt för bilder”" aria-describedby="" rel="nofollow">KÖP</a></div></li>
<li class="product type-product post-10244 status-publish instock product_cat-elsystem-duett has-post-thumbnail purchasable product-type-simple">
    
<div data-item_id="10244" data-action="alg-wc-wl-toggle" class="alg-wc-wl-btn add alg-wc-wl-thumb-btn alg-wc-wl-thumb-btn-abs alg-wc-wl-thumb-btn-loop" style="inset: 17px auto auto 17px; display: block;">
    <div class="alg-wc-wl-view-state alg-wc-wl-view-state-add">
        <i class="far fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="alg-wc-wl-view-state alg-wc-wl-view-state-remove">
        <i class="fas fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
            <i class="loading fas fa-sync-alt fa-spin fa-fw"></i>
    </div><a href="https://motoroldies.rocketdigital.se/produkt/testprodukt-for-bilder/" class="woocommerce-LoopProduct-link woocommerce-loop-product__link"><img loading="lazy" decoding="async" width="150" height="113" src="https://motoroldies.rocketdigital.se/wp-content/uploads/2024/05/1161037-1-3-150x113.jpg" class="attachment-woocommerce_thumbnail size-woocommerce_thumbnail" alt=""></a><a href="https://motoroldies.rocketdigital.se/produkt-kategori/duett/elsystem-duett/" rel="tag">Elsystem Duett</a><h2 class="woocommerce-loop-product__title">Testprodukt för bilder</h2>
    <span class="price"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi>500,00&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">kr</span></bdi></span></span>
<div class="woocommerce-loop-product__buttons"><a href="?add-to-cart=10244" data-quantity="1" class="button product_type_simple add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart" data-product_id="10244" data-product_sku="3" aria-label="Lägg till i varukorgen: ”Testprodukt för bilder”" aria-describedby="" rel="nofollow">KÖP</a></div></li>




This is the code of the function you are calling:
/**
 * Returns the product categories in a list.
 *
 * @param int    $product_id Product ID.
 * @param string $sep (default: ', ').
 * @param string $before (default: '').
 * @param string $after (default: '').
 * @return string
 */
function wc_get_product_category_list( $product_id, $sep = ', ', $before = '', $after = '' ) {
    return get_the_term_list( $product_id, 'product_cat', $before, $sep, $after );
}

which calls this one:
function get_the_term_list( $post_id, $taxonomy, $before = '', $sep = '', $after = '' ) {
    $terms = get_the_terms( $post_id, $taxonomy );
 
    if ( is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {
        return $terms;
    }
 
    if ( empty( $terms ) ) {
        return false;
    }
 
    $links = array();
 
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $link = get_term_link( $term, $taxonomy );
        if ( is_wp_error( $link ) ) {
            return $link;
        }
        $links[] = '<a href="' . esc_url( $link ) . '" rel="tag">' . $term->name . '</a>';
    }
 
    /**
     * Filters the term links for a given taxonomy.
     *
     * The dynamic portion of the hook name, `$taxonomy`, refers
     * to the taxonomy slug.
     *
     * Possible hook names include:
     *
     *  - `term_links-category`
     *  - `term_links-post_tag`
     *  - `term_links-post_format`
     *
     * @since 2.5.0
     *
     * @param string[] $links An array of term links.
     */
    $term_links = apply_filters( "term_links-{$taxonomy}", $links );  // phpcs:ignore WordPress.NamingConventions.ValidHookName.UseUnderscores
 
    return $before . implode( $sep, $term_links ) . $after;
}

Since it has a before and an after parameter (I mean wc_get_product_category_list), you can define a wrapper for it, like
<?php echo wc_get_product_category_list( $product->get_id(), ', ', '<span class="product-category-container">' . _n( 'Category:', 'Categories:', count( $product->get_category_ids() ), 'woocommerce' ) . ' ', '</span>' ); ?>

and then you can create CSS rules, like
span.product-category-container a[rel="tag"] {
    /*Your styling here*/
}


Thank you! I tried to add this to my css code: span.product-category-container a[rel="tag"] {font-size: 10px;} and this to my php code: add_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', function ( ){
global $product;
echo wc_get_product_category_list($product->get_id());
}, 1 );
echo wc_get_product_category_list( $product->get_id(), ', ', '' . _n( 'Category:', 'Categories:', count( $product->get_category_ids() ), 'woocommerce' ) . ' ', '' );  However the text does not change. Am I putting it wrong? Thank you!

@SofiaHjärtbergZintio can you right-cllick on your browser window, click on inspect (or inspect element), check the section where the content of this function is displayed, edit your question and paste the chunk of HTML you have thusly found? That would clarify the problem. Thank you.

Instrument PV is this the right one?

@SofiaHjärtbergZintio is its parent a span with a class of product-category-container? Can you edit your question with more of the structure around this section?

added the code as a screenshot. It does not come up anything about the product-category-container so I guess that did not work for me

@SofiaHjärtbergZintio then these are the possible reasons: 1. There might be server cache in use that caches all pages and the new changes were just not cached yet, rendering the old version of the page in use 2. The function might have been overriden by some subclass or changed 3. You might have multiple uses of that function and your change is applied for a different use than the one you expected. You will need to carefully debug and see whether your code is indeed applied in some manner, either using a step-by-step debugger (xdebug) or experimenting with the code.

ok thank you! I dont have a cache plug in yet since the store is not live and ready yet. I will try to find the reason.
